# I have a function called but the result is logged before the function finish executing

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I have a function called `createUser`, this function is supposed to try and save the user in the database. If that is successful, then it return true, otherwise false.
Here is the code for that:

```
exports.createUser = (user) => {
  const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
  const hash = crypto
    .pbkdf2Sync(user.password, salt, 1000, 64, "sha512")
    .toString("hex");
  user = {
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
    dateOfBirth: user.dateOfBirth,
    state: user.state,
    username: user.username,
    email: user.email,
    salt: salt,
    hash: hash,
  };
  const newUser = new User(user);

  newUser.save(function (err) {
  if(err) {
      const result = {
        done: false,
        error: "Username or Email already in use.",
      };
      console.log(result); //it gets logged successfully
      return result;
    } else {
      const result = {
        done: true,
        username: data.username,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
      };
      return result;
    }
  });
};
```

And then I have another function that calls it. When i try to log its result, it returns undefined. And i have noticed that it actually gets logged before the function finish executing.

This is where I am calling the createUser function

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await userController.createUser(req.body);
    console.log(result);
    .
    .
    .
```

This is the log result:
[image]

As you can see, the undefined gets logged before the result object. Which means log(result) of the createUser function gets called before the createUser function actually finish executing. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the problem is that you are console logging without waiting the createUser's promise to finish, so the results is 'undefined'. If you try something like

```
const result = await userController.createUser(req.body) || 'Promise not finished';
```

Result should always be equal to 'Promise not finished', because the API call takes more time than console.log.

You can double check this into your browser's inspector tab "Network'  where at some point you will get the right result.